# Beginning Haskell - cannot understand proof

Tags: trigonometry, logic, proof-writing

I've just started reading "Thinking Functionally with Haskell" by Richard Bird

In the preface he states :

[image]

And after stating the proof he also states the proof will be used throughout the book.

What is this proof ? I do not understand this proof or why it will be used throughout this book ?

What background reading should I use in order to understand this proof ?

Comment: Which step(s) do you not understand? If it's the last step of the derivation that you don't understand, you need to substitute $1 - \sin^2 \alpha$ for $\cos^2 \alpha$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s not the proof itself that will be used throughout the book: it’s the *format* of the proof, in which the justification for each equality is given in curly braces immediately after the equals sign. For instance, the third step,

$$\sin2\alpha\cos\alpha+\cos2\alpha\sin\alpha=2\sin\alpha\cos^2\alpha+\cos2\alpha\sin\alpha\;,$$

is justified by the reason

$$\{\text{since }\sin2\alpha=2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha\}\;.$$

Apply this double angle formula to $\sin2\alpha\cos\alpha$, and you get

$$(2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha)\cos\alpha\;,$$

which simplifies to $2\sin\alpha\cos^2\alpha$.